# Spark job injection by Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-spark, dependency-injection

I have been realized a job under `Spark` using: `spark-core_2.11`, & `spark-sql_2.11`, my class who launch the job as is defined as follows:

```
public class App 
{
    public static SparkSession sparkSession = SparkConnection.getSession();

    App( SparkSession sparkSession ) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException{

        new MyFirstJob( sparkSession );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException 
    {
                new App( sparkSession );    
    }  
}
```

this is my `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Job_Spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>v0</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>v0</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now I want to do this injection using `Spring`, not `Spring boot`, I know that we must define `Spring` as `master`, I'm searching how exactly,

Answer (score 0):

First you must run spark master and workers:
go to bin in spark folder run cmd command

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```

this will start spark master then you will have your master URL
next run another cmd with this command:

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker SPARK_URL
```

now spark is ready to be used from spring.
In spring controller you can connect to this spark master with this code

```
SparkSession sp = SparkSession.builder().master(SPARK_URL).getOrCreate();
```

Comment: I'm in **maven** project and i don't have the possibility to touch the bin folder of 'Spark'

Comment: why u need maven to touch bin folder you can with java execute a batch file holding those commands like on postconstruct of your  spring controller

Comment: I have been started with a maven project in eclipse, so i can add a documentation and update thi job.